# Merging two text files using Shell script in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I have three String varibales in my VBA code as below:

```
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FooterFilePath As String
Dim PlusChar As String

FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Bin\file.txt"
FooterFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Bin\footer.txt"
PlusChar = Chr(43)  'i.e. "+" sign
```

Now I am trying to merge `FilePath` and `FooterFilePath` and write the combined result in `FilePath` again i.e. overwriting it. For that I am using followng line which doesn't work:

```
Shell "cmd.exe copy /c & FilePath & PlusChar & FooterFilePath & FilePath", 0
```

I know I have syntaxing issue here but I just don't know how to pass three variables into Shell command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the variables *outside* the enclosing double-quotes. also you should insert blanks between the different names so that your command does not get the names combined in one name. Try this:

```
Shell "cmd.exe copy /c " & FilePath & " " & PlusChar & " " & FooterFilePath & " " & FilePath, 0
```

But:

- There's no reason to have a variable for the `+`
- Your drive's name is missing in the paths
- `/C` is an option for the `cmd` program, not for the `copy` command.
- It is useful to print that expression in the immediate window to verify it before execution. To do so, you can put it in a `String` variable and `debug.print` it before execution:

This would be correct:

```
Dim FilePath As String, FooterFilePath As String, myCommand As String

FilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "C:\Bin\file.txt"
FooterFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "C:\Bin\footer.txt"

myCommand = "cmd /c copy " & FilePath & " + " & FooterFilePath & " " & FilePath
Debug.Print myCommand
Shell myCommand, 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. VBA doesn't complain and your line of code compiles successfully but files are still not merged!

Comment: @Bababarghi your file paths seem to be missing the drive letter part, i.e. `"c:\Bin\file.txt"`. Also there's  no need to define a variable for the `+` sign.

Comment: I am afraid that's not the case. Same variable name has been used in different part of the code with successful outcomes. Only `Shell` command doesn't work as intended

Comment: @Bababarghi see the edited answer. Detailed explanation for some issues. Inportantly, check the command in the immediate window and post it back here if it still doesn't work.

Comment: The second bullet point in your answer is not correct. In fact, I think I found why Shell command is not working.  Based on `Debug.Print myCommand`, the `mycommand` string length is currently  559 charchters (considering my text files are stored on a Network Drive). Can the command length be the issue by any chance?

Comment: @Bababarghi granted the drive's name might be skipped but I wouldn't omit it unless when using a UNC name. `cmd` does have a limit but it's about 2000 characters, so that shouldn't be the issue. A possible issue is if your actual file names contains some spaces in them , in which case you should enclose them by quotes.

Comment: According to Google, it turned out "Maximum path length is 260 in Windows Vista/7"